# Meteor Vue Tracker - Unable to Watch Subready. Computed property with subready is not working either

Tags: meteor, vue.js

I am trying to move my project from blaze to vue.

I am using meteor 1.6.1 and [vue-meteor-tracker](https://github.com/meteor-vue/vue-meteor-tracker).

I had a case where in a component a subscription should take place only when the other subscription is ready.

I wrote the following code and faced the problems mentioned in the comments.

```
export default
  data: ->
    filter: null

  computed:
    subscriptionReady: ->
      # this gets called only once and the value does not change even when $subReady.users changes.
      @$subReady.users


  meteor:
    $subscribe:
      filter: []
    filter: -> Filter.findOne()

  watch
    '$subReady.filter': (value) ->
      console.log('this watch is not working')
      if value
        @$subscribe('users', @filter)
    '$subReady': (value) ->
      console.log('this watch is not working either')
    'filter': (value) ->
      # this will work but i can not use this as I need the below subscription to run even when there is no filter in the db.
      if value
        @$subscribe('users', @filter)
```

I can do null handling in publication but in the above case when filter is not present, there is a default value for filter.The problem is when the filter subscription is not ready users data is returned with default filter value. The users subscription gets called again when the filter subscription is ready.

Note: The above case is not exactly the same as I am facing in the project so I apologize if I missed something and the question is not clear.

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.